# Flutter/Hive - How to write Widget positional arguments?

Tags: flutter, class, dart, widget, flutter-hive

*(I am sorry I can only post a portion of my code, I hope what I have here is enough.)*

In this code, I need to call `buildApiBox` into the `page_ApiBox` class. But I also need to pass `apibox.api_key` which is already connected to a variable in a different class.

**Any advice is appreciated. I am new to Flutter/Dart.**

(Part of) My Code:

```
class page_ApiBox extends StatefulWidget {
    const page_ApiBox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<page_ApiBox> createState() => _page_ApiBoxState();
  }

  class _page_ApiBoxState extends State<page_ApiBox> {


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: buildApiBox(context, apibox)
      );
    }
  }

  Widget buildApiBox(BuildContext context, apiBox apibox) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('API BOX')
        ),
        body: Text(apibox.api_key) //I need to display what is inside the variable
    );
  }
```

Here is a photo of my code. As you can see, `apibox` in line 90 is undefined.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter in the `page_ApiBox` constructor like this here.

```
class page_ApiBox extends StatefulWidget {
    const page_ApiBox({Key? key, required this.apibox}) : super(key: key);
    final apiBox apibox;

    @override
    State<page_ApiBox> createState() => _page_ApiBoxState();
  }
```

Then if you want to get access to your variable you need to use `widget.` since it is a [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

```
  class _page_ApiBoxState extends State<page_ApiBox> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: buildApiBox(context, widget.apibox)
      );
    }
  }

  Widget buildApiBox(BuildContext context, apiBox apibox) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('API BOX')
        ),
        body: Text(apibox.api_key) 
    );
  }
```